# Linq: Adding the Where clause "or" condition

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

```
 carList = allCars.Where(a => a.CarCategory.Any(a => categoryIds.Contains(a.CarId))).ToList();
           &&
           allCars.Where(b => b.BrandCategory.Any(b => brandsIds.Contains(b.BrandId)).ToList();
```

I'm sending 2 arrays.

**categoryIds & brandsIds**

I pass the ones matching categoryIds to the carList var into View, but with the query "or", if the customer chooses a brand in addition to the category, I want to pass two queries.

If the sports car category is selected, it should look like the following.

Car1 - Honda, Car2 - Bmw, Car3 - Honda, Car4 - Mercedes, Car5 - Honda

If the sports car category is selected and the brand is selected, it should look like the following.

Car1, Car3, Car5

Comment: `&& (brandIds.Count == 0 || b.BrandCategory.Any(b => brandsIds.Contains(b.BrandId))` ?

Comment: if a brand is selected, do you want to return those that match either category or brand or do you want to only return those that match both?

Comment: @DerDingens Choosing a category is mandatory, but the brand is optional.. If both category and brand are selected, I want to return those that match both. I updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you don't use "a" twice, you're using it once for the entries in *allCars* but also for those in *a.CarCategory*. May use some detailed names like

```
carList = allCars.Where(currentCar => currentCar.CarCategory.Any(currentCarCategory => categoryIds.Contains(currentCarCategory.CarId))).ToList();
       &&
       allCars.Where(currentCar => currentCar.BrandCategory.Any(currentCarBrand => brandsIds.Contains(currentCarBrand.BrandId)).ToList();
```

Aside from that, you can just use *explicit or* inside that *where*, so something like this

```
carList = allCars
    // get those that match categoryIds
    .Where(currentCar => currentCar.CarCategory.Any(currentCarCategory => categoryIds.Contains(currentCarCategory.CarId)) 
    // to include brands
    && 
        // check if brands are provided
        (
            // in case they are not this will ignore the any below
            (brandIds == null || !brandIds.Any())
            ||  
            // in case there are, get those match the brands
            currentCar.BrandCategory.Any(currentCarBrand => brandsIds.Contains(currentCarBrand.BrandId))
        )
    .ToList();
```

should do.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this query:

```
carList = allCars.
            Where(a => categoryIds.Contains(a.CarId)
           &&(
                 (brandsIds=null 
                || brandsIds.Length ==0)
                 )
                 || brandsIds.Contains(a.BrandId)
               )
            )
           .ToList();
```